# mysql query gives wrong results from five tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have created a mysql query to generate my intended result.

Actually it gives me wrong results. My intended results are to get the current stock by subtracting the SUM of sold Stock from the SUM of shipment Stock.

My database tables are:

`items(itemId,itemUniqueNo,itemSize,itemColor....)`
`prices(itemPrice,presentPriceBoolean,items_itemId....)`
`shipments(shipmentDate,noOfPairs,items_itemId,sources_sourceId....)`
`sources(sourceId,sourceName.....)`
`solditems(quantitySold,items_itemId....)`

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT itemId,itemUniqueNo,itemSize,itemGender,itemColor,sourceName,itemPrice,sourceName,
    (COALESCE(SUM(noOfPairs),0) - COALESCE(SUM(quantitySold),0)) AS quantityInStock
FROM(shoepalace.items 
    INNER JOIN shoepalace.prices ON items.itemId = prices.items_itemId AND presentPrice =1) 
    LEFT JOIN shipments ON shipments.items_itemId = items.itemId 
    INNER JOIN sources ON sources.sourceId = shipments.sources_sourceId 
    LEFT JOIN shoepalace.solditems ON items.itemId = solditems.items_itemId GROUP BY itemId
```

Let say :

```
itemId       shipmentQuantity       quantitySold     finalQuantity(quantityInStock)
2            15                     3                12
3            10                     0                10
4            7                      4                3
.......
```

Thanks:

Comment: Is what under "Let say" one of the tables or the final result?  It doesn't seem to match anything so I can't make it out.   You may want to give sample tables (with sample data), what results your query is currently getting and what result you want to get.  As it is your question is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run into an issue of bad/false sum() values if the two tables have multiple rows for the same ID, you could get a Cartesian sum() result.  To help resolve this, pre-query the aggregates from each respective table so you get only one record per ID (if available via your Coalesce testing), then just grab that.

```
SELECT 
      itemId,
      itemUniqueNo,
      itemSize,
      itemGender,
      itemColor,
      itemPrice,
      S1.sourceName,
      ( COALESCE( S1.ShipPairs ,0) 
      - COALESCE( S2.QtySold, 0) ) AS quantityInStock
   FROM
      shoepalace.items 
         INNER JOIN shoepalace.prices 
            ON items.itemId = prices.items_itemId AND presentPrice = 1
         LEFT JOIN 
            ( select items_itemId,
                     SUM(noOfPairs) as ShipPairs
                 from 
                    shipments 
                       INNER JOIN sources 
                          ON shipments.sources_sourceId = sources.sourceId
                 group by 
                    items_itemId ) as S1
            ON items.itemId = S1.items_itemId
         LEFT JOIN 
            ( select items_itemID,
                     SUM(QuantitySold) QtySold 
                 from 
                    solditems
                 group by
                    items_itemID ) S2
            ON items.itemId = S2.items_itemId
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sir, you are great. You have have solve my problem.There were a little mistakes in the query but i fixed it. It now gives me my intended result. THANKS.